# Swift passing two delegates by condition

Tags: swift

Currently, I am converting Obj-C code to Swift.

**Setup:**

**Protocol A**
func methodA()

**Protocol B**
func methodB

**Class C**

```swift
func passing() {
    if deleagteA?.methodA?() {}
    else if delegateB?.methodB?() {}
}
```

Originally in Objective-C, it were handled by if delegate is conforms A pass methodA, `else if` conforms B protocol then pass methodB. Since `Swift` no have or not need `responseToSelector` method, and came up with above implementation. Is there better way to write on Swift instead having empty block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted, it's not clear if your protocol methods are optional or not. This will work either way.

```swift
(delegateA?.methodA ?? delegateB?.methodB)?()
```

And if you've got a lot of them, you can put them into an array.

```swift
[delegateA?.methodA, delegateB?.methodB, delegateA?.methodA, delegateB?.methodB]
  .compactMap { $0 }
  .first?()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a solution more similar to the old one with only one delegate property you can do like this

```
class C {
    var delegate: Any?

    func passing() {
        if let delegate = self.delegate as? A {
            delegate.methodA()
        } else if let delegate = self.delegate as? B {
            delegate.methodB()
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little bit more code but you don't need 2 properties and avoid the risk of assigning 2 delegates at the same time

Comment: Not so much more if you use a bunch of `?`s. `( (delegate as? A)?.methodA ?? (delegate as? B)?.methodB )?()`

Answer (score -1):

It turns out `??` [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html) is the fix for this case.
`delegateA?.methodA() ?? delegateB?.methodB()`

Comment: checking for `nil` would also work for optional methods as far as I know.